# In the following example, would the public properties be considered Dependencies/Collaborators

Tags: design, unit-testing

In the code sample below. Would `UserId`, `Email`, and `UserType` be considered "dependencies" with respect to the `ChangeEmail` method? would they be considered "collaborators"? Is it a condition for a member to be of a complex type for it to be considered either?

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public UserType Type { get; private set; }
    public void ChangeEmail(int userId, string newEmail)
    {
        object[] data = Database.GetUserById(userId);
        UserId = userId;
        Email = (string)data[1];
        Type = (UserType)data[2];
        
        if (Email == newEmail)
        return;

        object[] companyData = Database.GetCompany();
        string companyDomainName = (string)companyData[0];
        int numberOfEmployees = (int)companyData[1];
        
        string emailDomain = newEmail.Split('@')[1];
        bool isEmailCorporate = emailDomain == companyDomainName;
        UserType newType = isEmailCorporate ? UserType.Employee : UserType.Customer;
        if (Type != newType)
        {
            int delta = newType == UserType.Employee ? 1 : -1;
            int newNumber = numberOfEmployees + delta;
            Database.SaveCompany(newNumber);
        }
        Email = newEmail;
        Type = newType;
        Database.SaveUser(this);
        MessageBus.SendEmailChangedMessage(UserId, newEmail);
    }
}
public enum UserType
{
    Customer = 1,
    Employee = 2
}
```

Comment: Curiously, the snippet doesn't show any of the two cases. `ChangeEmail` is setting up attributes, but it's not operating through or with them. The method could be rewritten so it doesn't make any reference to the members and it would still compile and work. Basically, the method doesn't depend on any of the members to actually do its job. The only it needs is `Database`

Comment: This code was copied from text. I assume that the properties would be used by clients of the class at some point, thus the public modifier.

Comment: Well, the question is in relation to `ChangeEmail`, not consumers. Anyways, it doesn't change the observation. The method will work with or without these members because it doesn't use them. Not sure if we can tag instance attributes as "dependencies". I guess it depends on the kind of object. If it's a service, then yes, dependencies are likely collaborators. If it's a POJO ... I don't see it so clear.

Answer (score 0):

This heart of this question is the definition of these terms. So lets dig up some definitions.

> Dependency (computer science) or coupling,
> a state in which one object uses a function of another object
>
> [wikipedia.org - Dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency)

> Collaborators
> (other classes) with which this class interacts to fulfill its responsibilities
>
> [wikipedia.org - Class Responsibility Collaboration Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-responsibility-collaboration_card)

Given that the usual way classes interact is through methods (which is a fancy name for a particular kind of function) it's easy to see these terms as meaning the same thing. However, they are not typically mixed together in the same literature. When I hear one mentioned vs the other it mostly tells me which books the speaker has been reading.